# How to Optimize a variable based on past data without any known objective function in Python

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, reinforcement-learning, genetic-algorithm

I am working on a non-linear optimization problem in which I don't have an equation to work on only having past data.

Creating a sample code snippet to work with

```
import pandas as pd

size = 100
min_d = 5
max_d = 20

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['S','D','A'])

df['S'] = np.random.random(size)
df['D'] = np.random.randint(min_d,max_d,size)
df['A'] = np.random.uniform(3,7,size)
df.head()
```

[image]

**Note :**
min_d <= D <= max_d

Based on the past data,
for a new row, I want to maximize the value for A by using the optimized value of D(based on the constraint given), using the given value of S(which can't be changed ).

I have very limited knowledge of optimization any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about this: https://pysot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Comment: @KarelMacek I am not sure how to use pysot, did you have reference to any similar implementation ?